# Finding and replacing all words that ends with 'ing'

Tags: php, regex, strpos

I'm trying to find and replace all words that ends with 'ing'. How would I do that?

```
$text = "dreaming";
if (strlen($text) >= 6) {

if (0 === strpos($text, "ing")) 
//replace the last 3 characters of $text <---not sure how to do this either
echo $text; 
echo "true";    
}
```

**Result:**

```
null
```

**Want Result:**

```
dream
true
```

Comment: This is not an amazing [mcve]. As a consequence, answers span a spectrum of different interpretations and approaches which will give very different results from different input strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$text = "dreaming";

if (substr($text, (strlen($text) - 3), 3) === 'ing') {
  $text = substr($text, 0, (strlen($text) - 3));
}
echo $text;
```

Comment: Not going to downvote this, because it does work -- but look into the examples Chris85 and myself has posted. They are a more complete solution for you. This particular code works like a less optimized version of str_replace.

Comment: @MiDri Ah, sorry. Maybe my title was a bit misleading. $text will only ever contain one word, because it was already exploded - I just didn't contain the codes for it because I didn't think it was relevant.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for replacing ing at the end of words whilst ignoring stuff starting with Ing as well as words with ing in the middle of them.

```
$output = preg_replace('/(\w)ing([\W]+|$)/i', '$1$2', $input);
```

Updated to reflect change specified in comments.

Comment: This will not match if the word is not followed by `\W`

Comment: \W is equivalent to NOT [a-zA-Z_] so literally anything that's not a continuation of a word.

Comment: Actually, it's equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Still, it will fail with `$input = "dreaming"`, as it's not followed by `\W`. Use word boundaries instead

Comment: You don't need a character class there nor the `+` quantifier. Also, a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` would work there: `preg_replace('/(\w)ing\b/', '$1', $input)`

Comment: Nice, never actually used the Word Boundaries metacharacter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use two regexs depending on what you are trying to accomplish your question is a bit ambiguous.

```
echo preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]+)ing((:?[\s.,;!?]|$))/', '$1$2', $text);
```

or

```
echo preg_replace('/.{3}$/', '', $text);
```

The first regex looks for word characters before an `ing` and then punctuation marks, white spaces, or the end of the string. The second just takes off the last three characters of the string.

Comment: The second one makes no sense.. you're telling it to replace any 3 characters before the end of the line with literally $1$2 (since you're not capturing anything from the regex)

Comment: @MiDri Oh yea, forgot to remove that replacement group, thanks (wouldnt hurt anything, just makes no sense.).

Comment: I do my regex checks really quick in javascript (behaves a bit differently) in javascript it uses the literal $1 and $2 when no replacement groups are captured.

Comment: Hmm maybe a flaw or feature of JS (I wouldn't want it doing that although I've never needed `$1` literally). PHP doesn't do that though, https://eval.in/464847. Also if I just double checked code though wouldnt of had that anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
$str = preg_replace('/\Bing\b/', "", $str);
```

`\B` (non word boundary) matches where word characters are sticking together.

Be aware it substitutes `king` to `k`. See [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hY4lU9/2)